# Rails 4 I18n incorrectly recognize locale :'language-conuntry' as :'language' like :'zh-CN' as :zh

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, locale

for example Rails will treat `:'zh-CN'` as `:zh`

in config/application.rb

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = [:'zh-CN'] # or ['zh-CN'.to_sym]
```

ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder#label will raise

```
:zh is not a valid locale
```

I am using Rails 4.1.0.rc1, Ruby 2.1.1 and keep gems latest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

solved by `I18n.config.enforce_available_locales = false` , then I18n will not try :language locale.

Answer (score 2):

You can set available_locales. Setting `enforce_available_locales` to false you are turning off the errors instead of adding your language to available_locales.

If you need language `zh` to be available, just add it to available_locales.

Example:

```
config.i18n.available_locales = [:"zh-CN", :zh]
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

`config.i18n.fallbacks = [:"zh-CN"]`